# reading port number as an argument and do stuff

Tags: python, sockets

I wrote the following script in python:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import socket
import sys
import os

host=sys.argv[1]
port=sys.argv[2]


if len(sys.argv) != 3:
    print 'Usage: python %s <HostName> <PortNumber>' % (sys.argv[0])
    sys.exit();

try:
        s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
except socket.error, msg:
        print 'Failed to creat socket. Error code: ' + str(msg[0]) + ' Error message: ' + msg[1]
        sys.exit();

try:
        host_ip=socket.gethostbyname(host)

except socket.gaierror:
        print 'Host name could not be resolved. Exiting...'
        sys.exit();

print 'IP address of ' + host + ' is ' + host_ip + ' .'

try:
    s.connect((host_ip, port)) #OR s.connect((host_ip, sys.argv[2]))
except socket.error, (value,message):
    if s:
        s.close();
    print 'Socket connection is not established!\t' + message
    sys.exit(1);

print 'Socket connected to ' + host + 'on IP ' + host_ip + 'on port number ' + port + '.'
```

But when I run it this error occures:

```
s.connect((host_ip, port))
return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
TypeError: an integer is required
```

What is wrong here?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `argparse` to process your arguments. It provides many useful features in addition to making it easy to fix your immediate problem (not making the port number an integer). Replace

```
host=sys.argv[1]
port=sys.argv[2]


if len(sys.argv) != 3:
    print 'Usage: python %s <HostName> <PortNumber>' % (sys.argv[0])
    sys.exit();
```

with

```
import argparse
p = argparse.ArgumentParser()
p.add_argument("host")
p.add_argument("port", type=int)
args = p.parse_args()
# And optionally
host = args.host
port = args.port
```

Comment: Seems it is more useful in complicated issues

Answer (score 3):

The error message is the answer.

`port` shall be an integer and you are passing in `str`

before you call `s.connect((host_ip, port))` do

```
port = int(port)
```

Answer (score 1):

`connect()` requires an integer for the `port` argument, and since you accepted `port` as an argument it's a string. Make sure you typecast it as an int - `s.connect((host_ip, int(port))`.

Answer (score 1):

The sys.argv list is a list of strings, so you should convert it to an integer with the build-in `int()` function:

`port = int(sys.argv[2])`